# Setting up relationship table with Google Places API

Tags: geolocation, google-places-api

I am creating an iOS app. I am trying to set up a local table for storing data that is associated with a google place. I am having difficulty figuring out what to use as the primary key.

I read through the google place documentation, http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/  and found that I can pass in my current location to retrieve a set of 'reference' id that can be used to get the place details. However, I cannot use that reference id as my primary key because "the same token is not guaranteed to be returned for any given Place across different searches." I want to reference the google place key in my database so that I can form a relationship with other tables in my database.

If I want to store local data based on the relationship of the google place, what would I use as the primary key? For instance, I want to store custom data like how many of my users 'liked' this google place in my database.

Answer (score 1):

Store any reference key as the primary key in the db. now the thing is

A single place can have many reference ids but all reference ids will point to the single location. 
eg if paris has 3 reference ids like 
1233adasdadsa
2333asdasdads
2334adasdaads
but each reference id will point to paris.
This is called as reverse geocoding.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the reference as the primary key.  There is a small chance that the place may change (drift) over time, so the reference is not necessarily guaranteed.

From the API documentation you linked to:

`reference` contains a unique token that you can use to retrieve additional information about this place in a Place Details request. You can store this token and use it at any time in future to refresh cached data about this Place, but the same token is not guaranteed to be returned for any given Place across different searches.

You can use the `id` to verify whether you're referencing the same place in your searches.  Ultimately, you'll need to set up some logic in your app to determine whether your reference brings up the same place (via ID).

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use 'id' for your primary key then, if it is indeed unique and consistent across various searches for a particular location? I'm having difficulty understanding the design reasoning behind having both an 'id' (unique & consistent across all searches) and 'reference' (unique & consistent only across one search)